# IF statement == not working

Tags: c#, if-statement

I for some reason can't wrap my head around why this doesn't work... here is my code and every time I try a different account that has NM or PT it always just shows .11 and I can't seem to figure out why....

```
// Declare tax variables
string salesTax = customerLookup.Rows[0].Cells[4].Text;
double nmTax = .15;
double jackTax = .014;
double ptTax = .013;
double noTax = .11;

//If statement to pull correct tax price based on which tax bracket they are in
if (salesTax == "NM")
    taxTextBox.Text = nmTax.ToString();
else if (salesTax == "JA")
    taxTextBox.Text = jackTax.ToString();
else if (salesTax == "PT")
    taxTextBox.Text = ptTax.ToString();
else
    taxTextBox.Text = noTax.ToString();
```

And if i do this code it shows NM or PT in the textbox so I am on the right cell... any help is appreciated:

```
taxTextBox.Text = salesTax.ToString();
```

Comment: make sure that there is no trailing spaces in the salesTax string, trim before comparing as well as casing

Comment: Also note that case will make a difference here.

Comment: What happens if you rewrite it to `if (salesTax.Trim() == "NM")`, etc.

Comment: Run it in a debugger and look at the value of `salesTax` to see why the comparisons are not working.

Comment: Debugging would find the problem with very little effort

Comment: Thank you @willemVanOnsem that did it I knew it was something simple I was missing..

Answer (score 2):

This can be caused only by the fact that your salesTax is not the values that you compare to. There are some differences, probably because of your input, use the debugger and find them.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.Trim()` fixed the issue.